# $\iiint (y^2+z) dxdydz$ under region $x+y+z=2, x=2, y=1, z=y$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm having trouble trying to find the interval.

I tried mapping it to $u=x+y+z$,  $v=x$,  $w=y$ to get
$$u=2$$
$$v=2$$
$$w=1$$
$$u-v-w=w$$

Is this in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your region is the union of the two regions $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:2-y-z\leq x\leq 2, z\leq y\leq 1, 0\leq z\leq 1\}$ and $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:2-y-z\leq x\leq 2, -z\leq y\leq 1, -1\leq z\leq 0\}$.

This can be determined by sketching the region in the $(y,z)$ plane.

Your integral is
$$\int_0^1\int_z^1\int_{2-y-z}^2(y^2+z)\,dx\,dy\,dz + \int_{-1}^0\int_{-z}^1\int_{2-y-z}^2(y^2+z)\,dx\,dy\,dz$$
The first integral can be calculated as follows:
$$\begin{align}\int_0^1\int_z^1\int_{2-y-z}^2(y^2+z)\,dx\,dy\,dz &= \int_0^1\int_z^1x(y^2+z)|_{2-y-z}^2\,dy\,dz\\ 
&= \int_0^1\int_z^1(y^3+yz+zy^2+z^2)\,dy\,dz\\
&=\int_0^1 \left(\frac{y^4}{4}+\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{zy^3}{3}+z^2y\right)\Bigg|_z^1\,dz\\
&=\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{5}{6}z+z^2-\frac{3}{2}z^3-\frac{7}{12}z^4\right)\,dz\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{4}z+\frac{5}{12}z^2+\frac{1}{3}z^3-\frac{3}{8}z^4-\frac{7}{60}z^5\right)\Bigg|_0^1\\
&=\frac{61}{120}
\end{align}$$
The second integral can be calculated similarly, and is equal to $\frac{7}{120}$. Therefore, the answer is $\frac{68}{120}=\frac{17}{30}$.

Comment: I was given a final answer of $\frac{17}{30}$

Comment: How would you intuitively approach the intervals and know which is the lower and upper bound? I'm having trouble figuring it out

Comment: In the $(y,z)$ plane, we have the boundaries $y=1$ and $z=y$. The boundaries $x+y+z=2$ and $x=2$ give us the boundary $y+z=0$.The region in the $(y,z)$ plane bounded by the three lines $z=-y$, $z=y$ and $y=1$ is the one I give in my answer.

Comment: And we cannot have $2\leq x\leq 2-y-z$, since if we did, $y$ and $z$ could take arbitrarily large negative values, which would give an unbounded region.